# Creating elements dynamically and adding functions with different parameters.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating anchor tags dynamically and I want them to call a function that has a set parameter for each one.

Example:

```
<div class="AnchorHolder">
   <a onclick="someFunction(1)">someText</a>
   <a onclick="someFunction(2)">someText</a>
   <a onclick="someFunction(3)">someText</a>
</div>
```

I've tried

```
$("#AnchorHolder").append("<a>" + someText + "</a>").click(function (e) {
    someFunction(someIntVariable);
});
```

but instead connects all of the anchors to the IntVariables current value, whereas I wanted the previous ones.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would suggest you to try `data` attributes. As far I know they are made for that porpuse. See:

```
$("#AnchorHolder").append("<a href='#' data-myvar='" + someIntVariable + "'>" + someText + "</a>");

// Keep the event binding out of any loop, considering the code above will be called more than once...
$("#AnchorHolder").on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    alert($(this).data("myvar"));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8F6T/)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the click on the new element, tack it onto that element, and not on the #AnchorHolder element:

```
var newAnchor = $("<a>" + someText + "</a>").click(function (e) {
  someFunction(someIntVariable);
});
$("#AnchorHolder").append(newAnchor);
```

Or, alternatively to get each `<a>` to call the someFunction with their postion-inside-the-div:

```
$("#AnchorHolder a").each(function(idx) {
  var a = $(this);
  a.click(function() { someFunction(idx); });
});
```

Comment: Well I tried it now and the older anchors are not able to call the function, just the latest one. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a html element as following

```
   $('<a>').attr("onclick","fun('hi')").html('Some text').appendTo("#AnchorHolder");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Kelsey Abreu : did this help you?